# get referrer URL in wp-admin-ajax.php

Tags: wordpress, admin-ajax

I used some X hook in function.php. I need to know which page trigger this action, need to get referrer URL and redirect to that page with success meassage.

```
function bp_plugin_hook_activity_posted_update( $content, $user_id, $activity_id, $event_id ) {

$userEmails = 'xxx@gmail.com';

if(!empty($userEmails))
    wp_mail( $userEmails, 'shared an event!', "content" , 'Content-Type: text/html' );

}

add_action( 'bp_activity_posted_update', 'bp_plugin_hook_activity_posted_update', 10, 3 );
```

Refer below AJAX resuest,

```
action:post_update
cookie:bp-members-scope%3Dall%26bp-activity-oldestpage%3D1
_wpnonce_post_update:df8c1689d4
content:http://localhost/sitename/event/atx-startup-crawl-at-austin-startup-week-2017/
event_id:1132
visibility:followers
object:
_bp_as_nonce:
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get it using [wp_get_referer()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_referer) and [wp_get_original_referer()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_original_referer) functions.

Answer (score -1):

Create js referrer  variable with `wp_localize_script`, in data ajax pass this variable and process it in your function

Comment: would you explain bit briefly

Comment: @GNANA I do not see your code. Therefore answered abstractly

Comment: This is core wp-admin-ajax action, refer below for AJAX request , action:post_update
cookie:bp-members-scope%3Dall%26bp-activity-oldestpage%3D1
_wpnonce_post_update:df8c1689d4
content:http://localhost/sitename/event/atx-startup-crawl-at-austin-startup-week-2017/
event_id:1132
visibility:followers
object:
_bp_as_nonce:

Comment: I don't see what the benefit of involving `wp_localize_script` would be? If there was a good reason for this, then you forgot to include it in your 'abstract' answer. This isn't very helpful.